# Why doesn't my new app appear in the Motorola Milestone market?

Tags: android, google-play

This is my manifest.xml

Any idea why my app doesn't appear in Motorola milestone market

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.catom.dekel"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part:

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

It looks like you're trying to support everything, so there is no need to add this restriction.